# Http POST requests on Heroku running Springboot app

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

I've successfully deployed my `Springboot` app on `Heroku`. I'm also able to make get request like :

```
curl GET 'heroku-url'
```

Correctly returns :

```
{"id":1,"user_id":1,"title":"rneptdqxen","image":"","price":0.0,"description":"Niente"}
```

but not POST, if I try this :

```
curl -X POST 'heroku-url -d '{}' '
```

An error is thrown :

```
empty string within braces in URL position 49
```

If I change `heroku-url` to `127.0.0.1:8080/...`, build `Springboot` app locally then `POST` request works so I think that the request is correct, probably I'm missing something about quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try

```
curl -X POST  -d '{}' 'heroku-url'
```